# Is it possible to display a transparent image over a component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am using `React Native` to build an app. I am coming from web background. I'm wondering if this is possible in `React native expo` app.
In `React.js` when building for web, I usually call a transparent loading icon on top of a component or a page. I can apply opacity to it. For instance, a user trying to login, the login page will still remain on the screen and a transparent loading icon appears immediately the user clicks on the login button to make a request to the API.
The login page and loading icon will leave the screen after the API call has been fulfilled.

I would like to replicate same in `React Native`. Currently, I have a transparent loading gif which I called on the login screen.
When the user dispatches an action which calls the `API`, I set the loading state to true.
Unfortunately, this makes only the loading image to show on the screen and not over the login screen. This gives an ugly look with a white background.
I would like the loading icon to be displayed on top of the login screen until the `API` call is successful. Here is part of the code:

```
 const handleUserLog = async ()=>{
    dispatch(updateAppLoader(true))//I set the loading state to be true which calls the image
    const logDetails = {
    user_username: userLogin.user_username,
    user_password: userLogin.user_password,
  }

  dispatch( callLogIn(logDetails));
  }

return(
   <SafeAreaView>
     {
     appLoad && <Image source={assets.loading} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} 
     esizeMode='contain'/>
     }

    <Login Component>

     //Login design and setup here....

    </Login Component>
  </SafeAreaView>
 )
```

If I remove the `Image Loading Icon` the login component will always remain on the screen until the `API` request is fulfilled before moving to the next screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use `ImageBackground` component of react native

Example:

```
import { ImageBackground } from "react-native"

return(
  <SafeAreaView>
    <ImageBackground
      source={image} // replace your image
      resizeMode="cover"
      style={imageBackgroundStyle} // replace your style
    >
      <Login Component>
        //Login design and setup here....
      </Login Component>
   </ImageBackground>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
```

Ref: https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but this won't give the desired result. It placed the image as a background which defeats the purpose. The image should actually be at the top level respecting position absolute setting  and transparent BG.

Comment: I have achieved what I'm looking for. It was a simple CSS property that I was missing.